# Rename the [efs] tag to [windows-efs]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The [efs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efs) tag is for the Windows Encrypted File System (as its brief wiki excerpt indicates). These days, however, most people working with EFS are working with *Amazon* EFS, which has its own tag, [amazon-efs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-efs). As we know, people are lazy, so they just type in `efs` in the tag section and move on... not realizing that's the wrong tag. Luckily, I just finished (slow going at only four or five questions per day) an effort of re-tagging such questions appropriately.

To ensure users don't make it a problem again and start mistagging, can the [efs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efs) tag please be renamed to [windows-efs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-efs) for clarity/to reduce tag misuse?

*Possibly* the original tag [efs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efs) should then be synonymized with [amazon-efs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-efs) as well, so long as I'm not missing something else out there that uses the EFS acronym...

Comment: A significant portion of those Windows EFS questions seem off-topic as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm on record as not being a big fan of TLAs, so it should come as little surprise that my preferred solution to resolve the ambiguity was just to use the full name of the feature, which is Encrypting File System (EFS). Therefore, the new name for the tag is [encrypting-file-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encrypting-file-system). All questions which were formerly tagged [efs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efs) are now merged into that tag. The tag [windows-efs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-efs) is also there as a synonym.

The original [efs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efs) is no more, precisely because it is inherently ambiguous. Hopefully it does not return, since entering "efs" will now suggest either [windows-efs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-efs) or [amazon-efs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-efs).

Speaking of [amazon-efs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-efs), I've also added a synonym there mapping it to [elastic-file-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elastic-file-system). But Amazon doesn't use that name to refer to it as much as they use "EFS", so I've held off on making the expanded version the main tag.